# Why do I need Luck and Endurance?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I currently don't have rooms that would need those two skills (I have just opened Classroom), so why do I need dwellers with those skills?

Answer (score 29):

Luck gets you caps and rushing capabilities!! No joke, its what the chance of getting caps when you gather resources from a room is based on. It also states it has a direct impact on chance of failure when you rush a room. ***UPDATE*** Luck definitely has an impact on what you find out in the wasteland. I had one high and one low luck person go out on around 24hr wanderings. The one with high luck clearly had the better gear. They also ran into the better gear much more quickly than the guy with low luck.

Endurance is your health/ability to take damage. Makes you more stout when you get raided and such as well as while out exploring. It is also used in the final room, the Nuka Cola bottling factory, which gives food and water.

Comment: I think this is the better answer. :-)

Comment: @Ionic Thanks, I will be adding in more info the more I play.. such is the way of new games :D

Comment: Dwellers with high endurance will also be happy when assigned to stand around the storage rooms.

Comment: @Dallium True, but its generally better to assign those guys to the learning rooms and raise their other stats so you can send em out to the waste.

Answer (score 5):

Luck is for:

- [Increased chance of caps when collecting resources.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/260268/72346)
- [Reduced chance of rush failure.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/224005/72346)
- Increased chance of finding caps in the wasteland.
- [Preferred production skill for workshops, depending on current recipe.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/259096/72346)
- Completing "raise luck of x dwellers " challenge.
- Increased chance of VATS (critical hits) on quests.
- Meeting quest requirements.

Endurance is for:

- Reduce radiation damage in the wasteland and on quests.
- [Increased HP on level-up.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235830/72346)
- Preferred production skill for Nuka Cola Bottlers.
- [Preferred production skill for workshops, depending on current recipe.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/259096/72346)
- [Preferred skill (counts for happiness and assignment challenge, but no other benefit) for storage rooms.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/225033/72346)
- Completing "raise endurance of x dwellers" challenge.
- Meeting quest requirements.

Comment: This is a pretty good answer, but at least one of these needs to describe how endurance actually works to increase hit points when leveling. Linking to [this other answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/235830/108003) would work.

Comment: @DCShannon enough links now?

Comment: Going above and beyond.

Answer (score 0):

Dwellers with higher luck increase the probability that when a room finishes making its product (e.g. electricity/food/water), it comes along with a caps bonus.

I believe Endurance is only useful for dwellers you send to scavenge outside of the vault, at least for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I have a guy (Abraham Washington as a matter of fact) and he's got 10 luck with equipped apparel. Every time I send him out into the wastes he'll get LOTS of caps and like 8-10 pieces of loot after about 4 hours of exploring. 
Every other dweller I send out gets less than half as much. 
Luck definitely influences how much loot you collect from the wastland.

Answer (score 0):

Endurance is used for the Nuka Cola Bottling room which produces food and water

Answer (score 0):

I believe endurance is also used in storage rooms

Comment: Used in Storage rooms how exactly?

Answer (score -1):

I think endurance also helps with fighting. I have deathclaw attacks and (maybe it's just a coincidence) it seems like the dwellers with higher endurance last a bit better healthwise. The dwellers in comparison have similar levels

Comment: That was already said in the highest voted answer second part. It increases their health/ability to take damage.