# Should I assign dwellers to the storage room?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I've played Fallout Shelter for a while now and normally use dwellers with appropriate SPECIAL stats for each room (**S**trength in the reactor, **P**erception in the water supply, etc).

However, I have a question regarding **E**ndurance. The only room which uses this is the storage room. It doesn't produce anything; it has no cooldown; it just does nothing...

Even if I just build and upgrade the warehouse, my stock capacity is increased. Is there any good reason for me to waste my dwellers by assigning them to storage rooms?

Comment: Only reason is protection from fire/radroaches. Maybe, haven't tried, it will make them happier using their higher Endurance than other lower stats somewhere else.

Comment: Well the roaches and the fire will disappear on it's own in those rooms. They will move to other rooms. But it won't hurt my stuff inside those warehouses.

Comment: Roaches can still invade rooms with people assigned to them. It's happened to me quite a few times, and like 2-3 today alone. One of the tips says that you can assign people to the storage room if you want to stash them somewhere temporarily, but you don't need them there for anything useful.

Comment: Regarding Endurance, that stat is also used by dwellers in the Nuka Cola Plants.

Comment: Ah I haven't the nuka cola plants currently. Thanks for this advice!

Comment: In addition to the obvious use of Nuka Cola bottlers, endurance is a relatively universal ability. While it won't improve your dwellers' job performance, it will help keep them alive, and thus is a very important skill for your explorers and for dwellers working near the vault entrance (and fighting lots of raiders/deathclaws).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the point of dwellers working in the warehouse?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242145/what-is-the-point-of-dwellers-working-in-the-warehouse)

Comment: @TheUnicornMaster What? This question comes way earlier and is better written imo. If anything, the other should be a duplicate of this.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see when it was posted

Answer (score 34, accepted):

While the storage rooms do not produce anything, putting E type dwellers in them will raise their happiness, improving your average happiness rating and earning you more caps from your daily reviews. It will also count towards "Place # dwellers in the right room" objective.

Comment: Well currently I train them in S,P or A for the basic rooms and place them in there. This makes them happy too. So in fact, due to your answer, I just can ignore them and put them to the training and afterwards in the correct room too. Right? :-)

Comment: Yes, their correct room is determined by their highest SPECIAL, so training them will change it.

Comment: Yes I think this is the best answer. Currently I just have one dweller placed in them and the rest is training. I'm pretty sure I will get the last dweller also back in the training rooms. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

There are no reasons for placing dwellers in the warehouse that are related to actual warehousing, however there are other reasons:

1. Dwellers with high endurance become happy from being stationed in the warehouse.

   This is useful for doing something about all those 50% happiness dwellers on coffee brake; you can park them in the warehouse instead where they grow happy

   It is also needed for high Endurance dwellers when you get the task to put X dwellers in the right room
2. Dwellers don't gain experience from being in the warehouse.

   If you are training your dwellers to full endurance before you let them level, this is quite useful. It gives you more accessible place than the door queue to put your dwellers on "hold".

   (Dwellers gain HP each time they level, and the amount of HP gained depends on the Endurance they have at the moment they level. Once they have levelled there is no going back, so you might want your dwellers to stay at level 1 until you have trained them to full endurance.)
3. Dwellers in a warehouse contain incidents in that warehouse.

   For this reason alone it is worthwhile to have at least one dweller in every warehouse. The single dweller will contain the strength of the incident while you move other dwellers there to fully solve the incident.

   The alternative is to place your warehouses deep down at the bottom of your vault and stagger them, so that incidents can't spread.

   Also note in relation to point (2) that dwellers in a warehouse do gain a bit of experience from preventing incidents, but it is usually so rare for a particular warehouse to have an incident that it is negligible.

Comment: I posted this answer here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242145/what-is-the-point-of-dwellers-working-in-the-warehouse before realising that that question was a duplicate of this one. Perhaps someone with sufficient karma could mark the duplicate?

Comment: I can flag it for you. But why do you think it's a duplicate?

Comment: The way I read it, the question here is: "Is there any good reason for me to waste my dwellers by assigning them to storage rooms?", the linked question is: "What's the point of having dwellers working in the warehouse?" But it's you with the karma to mark it, so you be the judge :-)

Answer (score 3):

To all of that it has another purpose: more dwellers with a higher endurance in warehouse = more junk items from scrapping. I used to have the room empty and mostly I got nothing from scrapping weapons or clothes, now when it is full of high endurance people I got items from scrapping every time, so it seems like a big difference. If you are scrapping at all of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you put a dweller in the storage room with higher endurance stats than the rest, nothing will happen. Their happiness won't increase more than any other room, so just train their strength or agility.

Answer (score -5):

The warehouses are for those who needs protection. When there are roaches and fire, the people in your warehouse are safe from danger. It will make them happy.

Comment: This means if I have pregnant wives, they'll run to the warehouse?
Fire and roaches appear in the warehouse too, what about that?

Comment: The living quarters provide protection from incidents, not the warehouses.

Comment: Living quarters can have roaches and fire just like any other room.