# What are the factors that affect the random caps reward from production collection in Fallout Shelter?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I recently went through the trouble of maxing out the luck and relevant SPECIAL of all my dwellers in Fallout shelter. My vault has around 160 some odd dwellers and all of my rooms have dwellers with a SPECIAL for that room of 10 and luck of 10. For example, my gardens all have dwellers with a (natural) Agility of 10 and a luck of 10. Since doing this I've noticed I hardly ever receive cap rewards anymore. I used to be able to make thousands after a few rounds of collections over the course of five minutes. Now I make nothing.

So what are the factors for the caps reward algorithm? Did I screw something up by maxing out either luck or the room's SPECIAL?

Comment: For what I know, luck is the only factor for cap bonus. The SPECIAL of the room helps with rushes by lowering the chance of failure the higher the dweller's SPECIAL for that room are and the time it takes to produce the resource of the room.

Comment: Right, I think the issue I'm describing was a bug of the last version. I updated the app and am raking in the caps :)

Answer (score 3):

There are three factors.

Luck, luck, and luck.

Luck determines how many caps wasteland explorers get, and how many caps you get for successfully rushing a room's production. I believe, however, that the caps you get from leveling up a dweller is not affected -- they provide caps equal to their new level. Reach level 4? That's 4 caps. Obviously if you have 200 level 48 dwellers, you'll be raking in the dough soon enough.

Comment: Does Luck over 10 (outfit +7) affect the cap bonus when collecting a rooms production?

Comment: I thought I remember reading somewhere that any stat over 10 is wasted (it has a hard cap of 10), but I don't know for sure. With a +7 modifier, it probably wouldn't be difficult to compare two rooms of all 10 vs all 17 luck to see if the latter routinely produces more caps.