# What SPECIAL stats are useful in crafting rooms?

Tags: fallout-shelter

The new crafting rooms don't indicate what, if any, SPECIAL stat is best for dwellers in that room.

**Do any of the stats affect crafting weapons or armor in any way? How?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**All of them (but not at the same time)**

Each crafted item has a specific SPECIAL stat associated with it. Putting dwellers high in that stat into the room reduces the time to craft that item. Bonuses from outfits do count.

For crafted outfits, the stat is the same as the highest stat of the finished item. For weapons it's less easy to predict, but you can see the stat in the crafting list.

Comment: Have to be added that when you setup crafting, and then want to move new dweller to the room, it will actually show you +X in the stat needed for the actual crafting.

Comment: Yep, I see it now. The ability is indicated to the left of the item's name when you're choosing which item to craft.